# restrict count of editor panels in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to only have 2 editor panels open at once.
So when I OPTION + Click a file it opens in one of the open editors instead of a new one.

Is this possible in VS Code?

Comment: @Mark that is the amount of editors, not groups

Comment: You are right, you said "editor panels" so that is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to do that.